# Net core identity and expiration time for DefaultEmailProvider

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, token

Since the token that was generated automatically by `_userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user)` was very long, I decided to set the token creation like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(config => {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                config.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
                config.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
            })
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Now I get a 6 number code, but I'm not able to find out when this expire exactly.
Looking at what should generate the token [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e3253d4e4037e8fb90263ffd28b2b3d5e4806de9/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/Rfc6238AuthenticationService.cs) it says: "`Allow a variance of no greater than 9 minutes in either direction`" but at 8 minutes the token is already expired. I'd like to know when the token expire, and if there is any way to change this expiration time.

Answer (score 3):

Did you ever manage to fix your token expiry issue?
What I've seen on the net it states the token is valid for 1 day, but my tests indicate it is only 5 minutes.
I've tried the recommended fix:
`services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options => options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1));`
but it does not work.

EDIT:
Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63480369/15083397
Combining the above recommendation with
`.AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>>(TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider);` 
instead of .AddDefaultTokenProviders did the trick for me. It does generate a much longer token, but that's fine for me.